# Can I extend a tourist visa in India?

Tags: visas, india, visa-extensions, tourist-visas, turkish-citizens

I'm a Turkish girl from Istanbul. I'm planning a six-month trip to India in December and I've heard that getting a six-month visa is not easy from my country.

If I can only get 3 months instead of 6 months is it possible to extend the tourist visa in India?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick check on [IATA's visa & passport tool](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) with some made up data for a Turkish citizen born in 1980. I didn't get an indication that you are only allowed to stay up to three months. It was even mentioned that 10 year multi entry visa exists. When you have a multi entry visa you are apparently only allowed to reenter if you haven't been in india for more then 60 days. If you want to reenter earlier it is stated that you should contact an Indian mission. 
To be sure, you could try to fill in your details and see the IATA advise.

With that information you could then try to verify with an Indian mission in Turkey.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to think about all possibilities so asking a question again :) If I can only take 3 month single entry visa, is it possible to extend it in India ? Or to extend it in Sri Lanka, how can I take visa for Sri Lanka to extend my Indian visa ? To extend the visa must it be multi entry ? I know so much questions :) It's complicated :)